# What are known properties of matrices where off-diagonal elements are 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

Consider a matrix where the diagonal entries are anything but the off-diagonal entries are all one. I was able to find a formula for the determinant of this matrix, but what are other known properties? Does this matrix have a name? In particular is there a formula for its inverse?

Comment: It's the sum of a diagonal matrix and a rank one matrix, so the Sherman-Morrison formua would give an explicit formula for the inverse.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: Never seen this before, so thank you!

Comment: @TerryTao: This matrix may have no inverses.

Comment: @MarkSapir That's certainly true; from the original formulation one can choose the diagonal entries to be one and then the matrix is clearly singular. If we're going to study the inverse we need to make more assumptions, but if there is an inverse it will have a certain form. (I used the Morrison formula to find that inverse.) Bonus points for other quantities such as eigenvalues/eigenvectors, though.

Comment: @cgmil: The matrix can be invertible and the formula mat not give the inverse. For example matrix(2,1;1,1).

Comment: One would have to use a limiting argument to extend the Sherman-Morrison formula to the case where the diagonal matrix in question has a single zero coefficient.  As for eigenvalues, there is an identity of Lowner connecting the eigenvalues of the matrix to the entries of the diagonal matrix; see equation (24) of my recent survey on such identities with Denton, Parke, and Zhang at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03795.pdf , as well as the equation following it.

Comment: You've already worked out the determinant, but in general the formula for computing the determinant of a rank one perturbation is known as the matrix determinant lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: @TerryTao Well unfortunately the formula for the determinant is recursive in nature, so I don't have a great formula for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a matriix has the form $J +D,$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $J$ is a square matrix with all entries $1$. One small remark is that if $D$ has two of its diagonal entries equal to $\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $J+D$. This is because the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $D$ is at least two-dimensional and the $0$-eigenspace of $J$ has codimension one.